# Setting up PHP opcode caching under WampServer 2.1

Tags: wamp, php-apc

I've been trying to find information on installing(or enabling?) APC under WampServer 2.1, but every reference to it is either fragmentary or misleading. One forum post actually claimed it was already bundled and just left out of the php.ini file, but adding the enabling line did nothing, nor do I see any evidence the dll file even exists in the Wamp dir.

Can anyone provide the basic steps needed here?

I'm not particularly set on using APC, it's just recommended by the apps I'm trying to use. If xcache or eaccelerator are easier or better-documented, that's fine also. Thanks.